# Debug CUDA Dll from C#

Tags: cuda

We have a DLL containing the CUDA C code to do the calculation on GPU.

The DLL is called by C# application to feed the data and start the kernel functions.

Would it be possible to debug the DLL using Parallel Nsight?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In principle yes, provided you meet the other criteria for NSight debugging in terms of GPU configuration etc. Remember that VS only supports mixed mode debugging (stepping through from CLR to native code) in x86 builds.